# Setting up Google Cloud VPN between Webserver and Database servers

Tags: google-compute-engine, vpn, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to setup a VPN for my database servers on Google Cloud for a while but I have been running into some issues. My setup is as follows:

- 2 Webservers
- 2 Database Servers
- 1 Load balancer

The 2 webservers have a load balancer with a static IP, that routes traffic to one of the webservers. Both of the webservers are connected to the database servers. I am trying to create a VPN so both of the database servers are behind a private subnet and hidden from the general public. The only port that needs to open for the database servers are 8091 and 8092.

What is the proper way to create this, so the database servers are completely hidden from the general public?

Answer (score 1):

VPN is solution for connecting servers from 2 different networks so one can access other using their private  IP.

If your server and databases sit  both in GCE you doesn't need VPN, the servers can connect with their private IP without any other settings.

If your database servers sit in other network you need to set VPN between the two networks.